# product of different length list using itertools in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have the following lists:

```
sectors = ["A", "B"]

rows = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]

seats = [['ab', 'abcd', 'ab'], ['ab', 'abcd', 'ab', 'abcd']]
```

and I want to create products like `A1a, A1b, A2a, A2b, A2c ...`

this code

```
  combinations = []
  for i in range(len(rows)):
    c = list(zip_longest(repeat(sectors[i], len(rows[i])), rows[i], seats[i]))
    combinations += c

  for c in combinations:
    for x in product(*c):
       print("".join(x))
```

prints the desired results as `A1a A1b A2a A2b A2c A2d A3a ...`

Can this be solved in a better and more readable way, I am practicing `itertools` and it is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: You mean with separator? You can use `print(", ".join(x))` to list be separated with comma and one whitespace.

Comment: No, is there a more efficient/readable way to create all possible combinations(products) of the list in the example? It was more natural for me to use nested for loops, and itertools with its methods scrambled my head. Or the above code is acceptable.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do, and/or post your solution using for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want or if it is more elegant:

```py
from itertools import chain, product

combinations = product(
    sectors,
    chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(rows)),
    chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(seats)),
)
joined_combinations = map(lambda t: "".join(t), combinations)
list(joined_combinations)
# returns
['A1a', 'A1b', 'A1a', 'A1b', 'A1c', 'A1d', 'A1a', ...]
```

Explanation: Applying two times `chain.from_iterable` you can "unpack" individual characters from the nested lists, then creating the product of the items of the unnested lists (which creates 3-tuples) and finally join the items of each 3-tuple together. 
If you want to avoid duplicates you can put a `set()` around each argument in the `product`.

Comment: This is nice, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're creating triples from 3 nested lists, not Cartesian product, I think it may be more intuitive to `zip` the corresponding sublists and use a loop.

```
out = [sector + row + s for sector, rws, sts in zip(sectors, rows, seats) 
       for row, seat in zip(rws, sts) for s in seat]
```

If we want to use `itertools.product`, first repeat elements in `sectors` to match the lengths of sublists of the other lists and instead of creating the product elements manually like in the inner-most loop above, we iterate over the product itself. Of course, this is a lot like your own approach.

```
repsectors = [repeat(sector, len(rows[i])) for i, sector in enumerate(sectors)]
out = [''.join(x) for tpl1 in zip(repsectors, rows, seats) 
       for tpl2 in zip(*tpl1) for x in itertools.product(*tpl2)]
```

Output:

```
['A1a', 'A1b', 'A2a', 'A2b', 'A2c', 'A2d', 'A3a', 'A3b', 'B1a', 'B1b', 'B2a', 'B2b', 'B2c', 'B2d', 'B3a', 'B3b', 'B4a', 'B4b', 'B4c', 'B4d']
```

Comment: Smart, a somewhat difficult to read for me at this moment though.